# Charged particle equilibrium and Bragg-Gray cavity theory

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, medical-physics

About the charged particle equilibrium: 'In a small volume in the radiation field, some secondary electrons generated in the volume escape from the volume, and some electrons generated outside the volume deposit energy in the volume.' The secondary electron produced in the volume means that the electron produced by the photon in the volume leaves the volume due to Bremsstrahlung escape or the electron energy produced by the photon in the volume is large to ionize again to escape; Some electrons generated outside the volume deposit energy in the volume, which means that the end point of the electron’s movement is in the volume or that the electrons pass through the volume, but ionization occurs in the volume, and a part of the energy is deposited?

In Bragg-gray cavity theory, it says that the absorbed dose in the cavity is deposited entirely by charged particles crossing it, Does it mean that electrons pass through the volume, but are ionized in the volume and deposit some energy?